# Is decoding base64 strings safe

Tags: python, shell, flask, base64

I am submitting a user submitted file (which is supposed to be an image) but it is possible to submit a python file instead. It is sent to the backend Flask server as a `base64` encoded string, and decoded into a file in a child directory. I am worried about security, as the user submitted file will be included in dynamically generated HTML as a `img` `src="/images/fileThatIDecoded.jpg"` tag. I set the name and file extension myself. How can I validate that the decoded base64 string is a valid image? In order to use the imghdr module, I must already save the decoded string into a file, which might be unsafe.

---

**My code:**

```
mainPond.onaddfile = (err, item) => {
  if (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return;
  }
  const base64String = item.getFileEncodeBase64String();
  console.log(base64String)
  document.getElementById("hiddenFile").value = base64String
}
document.getElementById("submitbtn").onclick = function() {
  if (validateForm()) {
    document.getElementById("form").submit()
  }
}
```

```py
@app.route("/create", methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def create():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("create.html")
    else:
        imgdata = request.form.get("mainFile")
        if helpers.verifyImage(imgdata[:44]):
            imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgdata)
            filename = 'some_image.jpg'
            filename = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), "images", filename)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to assume that a user provided file is safe. The base64 encoding does not have any effect on safety.

To validate if the provided file is an image, you can use the [**imghdr module**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) in the standard library, which "determines the type of image contained in a file or byte stream."

You can pass the image as a byte stream directly to imghdr rather than saving it as a file.